# Anyone have idea how to run linux command in robot framework at backend

Tags: robotframework

I have to run this command
./emsInventory.sh -s 10 -i EMS1004 -p EMS -v 10.2.0.15.1 -d "EMS Patch " -c ems10/pass_ems10@rac_ems10.agnity.com

In robot framework to make sure that data is created or not

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Run Process`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process) in the Process library - this is its precise purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH Library in robot framework more details can be found here http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html.
Below examples could be useful

```
Execute Command And Verify Return Code
    [Documentation]    Often getting the return code of the command is enough.
    ...                This behaviour can be adjusted as Execute Command arguments.
    ${rc}=             Execute Command  echo Success guaranteed.    return_stdout=False    return_rc=True
    Should Be Equal    ${rc}            ${0}

Executing Commands In An Interactive Session
    [Documentation]    Execute Command always executes the command in a new shell.
    ...                This means that changes to the environment are not persisted
    ...                between subsequent Execute Command keyword calls.
    ...                Write and Read Until variants can be used to operate in the same shell.
    Write              cd ..
    Write              echo Hello from the parent directory!
    ${output}=         Read Until       directory!
    Should End With    ${output}        Hello from the parent directory!
```